# What are the additional tools and Frameworks that can be used with JSF developlemt?

Tags: jsf, web-applications, primefaces

I develop JSF applications with **Eclipse IDE** and **Tomcat server**.
With **Mojarra** and **Primefaces**.
Are the any other standard tools or Frameworks that I can use to make my app effective. like.,

- Code Review tools/frameworks.
- Unit testing tools/frameworks.
- Performance enhancement and analysis tools/frameworks.
- Report generation tools/frameworks.
- Any special Browser plugins
- etc.

Please share any tools which you are working with that might fit in to JSF development.

**EDIT**: If you are using any other tools that are not in above mentioned category,regarding JSF development. Please mention them too.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.
I heard for Performance Analysis you could use [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), I'm not sure whether it can be used for JSF or not. May be others can help you about rest of tools. I'm also waiting for answers.

Comment: Thanks JavaKid,for your answer. If u get to know about any other tools please post your answer.

Comment: Glad to help.  
sure I'll let you know if find answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code Review Tools - [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) Set you custom rules or ready to go rules and check you code against that rules.

Unit Testing Tools - [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)(Automated Web browser testing) in combination with & [JUnit](http://junit.org/)(Unit test your code)

Performance Analysis Tools - [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)(Create a test case with run with full load to know the breakage point)

Report Generation Tool - [Jasper Reports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)(Create cool looking reports using this tool). Can also create PDF and other docs. Refer to the site for more.

Any Special Browser Plugin - [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)   -->Helps you inspect element. A must for every web developer specially if you are developing in prime faces. Helps you see what exactly is under the hood.

Comment: Thansk Rohit. That was helpful.

Comment: From my experience, [mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) component for JUnit, is also very helpful to do tests with components that are unavailable while testing.